# I can't get the attachement of the email PHP

Tags: php, excel, imap

I have a script that connect to imap and get the excel files. It worked perfectly till today. For one of our supplier the script can't get the attached file. I think there is something wrong with the decoding email.

this is the code for decoding

```
 if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment'])
 {
    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($this->_mbox,$email_number,$i);
/* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
   if($flattenedParts[$i]->encoding == 3)
   {
       $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
   }
   elseif($flattenedParts[$i]->encoding == 4)/* 3 = BASE64 encoding */
   {
       $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
   }
 }
```

Is there other ways to decode the email with imap on php?

The array of imap

```
Array
(
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [type] => 0
        [encoding] => 0
        [ifsubtype] => 1
        [subtype] => PLAIN
        [ifdescription] => 0
        [ifid] => 0
        [lines] => 38
        [bytes] => 431
        [ifdisposition] => 0
        [ifdparameters] => 0
        [ifparameters] => 1
        [parameters] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [attribute] => charset
                        [value] => us-ascii
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [type] => 3
        [encoding] => 3
        [ifsubtype] => 1
        [subtype] => MS-TNEF
        [ifdescription] => 0
        [ifid] => 0
        [bytes] => 3584988
        [ifdisposition] => 1
        [disposition] => attachment
        [ifdparameters] => 1
        [dparameters] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [attribute] => filename
                        [value] => winmail.dat
                    )

            )

        [ifparameters] => 1
        [parameters] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [attribute] => name
                        [value] => winmail.dat
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: If the script worked perfectly 'til today, that signifies that your provider changed something in the mail configuration that broke it. Ask them what that was.

Comment: He changed his Excel file from .xls to .xlsx. But there are many other suppliers that send with .xlsx files and there is no problem but with this one I don't know why he can't get the file

Comment: Have you checked the value of `encoding`? If it is neither 3 nor 4 the attachment will not get decoded.

Comment: The value of encoding is 0 in the first array and 3 in the second. I edited my post

Comment: `[subtype] => MS-TNEF` -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Neutral_Encapsulation_Format

Comment: An idea how to decode the ms-tnef formats

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.imap-fetchbody.php#88662

Comment: Another way to solve it is to ask the sender to turn off TNEF in their mail client: https://www.buffalo.edu/ubit/service-guides/email/ubmail-powered-by-exchange/managing-your-ub-exchange-mail/configuring-outlook-to-not-send-winmail-dat-attachments.html

Comment: TNEF is obsolete.  I'm amazed the sender still has a client that uses that for external emails.

Comment: It seems really uncommun to get TNEF attachement files. I did not find a lot of things on the World Wide Web on it.